# Can I use navigation drawer for implementing filters on web?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

> I am using a navigation drawer like :

```
export default DrawerNavigator({
Dashboard: {screen: Dashboard},
   CreateLogin: {screen: CreateLogin},
   Test: {screen: Test}
}, {
   contentComponent: SideMenu,
   drawerWidth: 300,
   drawerPosition: 'right'
 });
```

> Now contentComponent: SideMenu have a list of check boxes like

```
renderItem={({ item, index }) => <CheckBox
title={item.name}
onPress={() => this.handleChange(item.id)}
checked={checked[item.id]} />
```

> In above code each check box have a specific index, now when user clicked on any check box I want to set state of my back screen, remember still I am on navigation drawer from where I am clicking on check boxes (or you can say filters).
>
> Now I want to change state on my listing page say ProductListing.js from where I am opening drawer navigator like

```
<Button
title='Filter'
onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
/>
```

Note: I know about how to pass state from parent to child & vice versa. Here Question is I am opening drawer menu where I have filters and these filters not a parent or child of ProductListing.js file. How can I update a state of ProductListing.js from SideMenu.js which one called in drawer navigator.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Thanks for asking this in write way.